# Why is this not centering? it gets pushed down

Tags: html, css

It would center properly without "designbox" but it WOULD BE PUSHED DOWN if I added "designbox". My goal is to center title beside designbox, but so far I got no luck. I tried every single centering method and nothing works!

Any ideas why is this happening and how should I fix this?

code:
https://jsfiddle.net/bjsowaxj/8/

html:

```
    <div class = "content-headercontainer">
<div class = "designbox">

</div>
<div class = "title">
Hi
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
    .content-headercontainer{
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    background: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.designbox{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width: 14px;
    background: orange;
 }
.title{
  position: relative;
  line-height: 56px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;

}
```

Comment: It's because of the `height:100%;` you have set on `.designbox`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give .title

```
vertical-align:top;
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bjsowaxj/9/)**

Comment: the browser is trying to align the text in the inline div with the baseline of the parent.
by saying "align top" you instead try to force the inline element to align with the top of its parent.

Comment: Thank you, I sort of get the idea; whenever I set designbox to verticla-align top every inline block that folows it would have a vertical-align: top;, but when I set title to vertical align top, only title itself would be aligned to top, any ideas why?

Comment: Its forcing the top of the line up to the parents top, and pulling up the baseline with it